# How to design body for sending large content in SMS?

Tags: android, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send an SMS to mobile.How to send large data in body ?orderid should be in online, product name in online,
price in online,status in online.How to arrange the body?

```
var data2 = db.collection("UserProfile").doc(mauths)
  .get().then(doc =>
   {
      mobile= doc.data().MobileNumber;
      console.log("mobile",mobile);
       // Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
       const accountSid = '======';
       const authToken = '=======';
       const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
       client.messages
       .create({
         body: "Your " + pn + " has been cancelled " ,// need to more content line by line
         from: '+-=======',    
         to: mobile
         }) 
         .then(message => {
         });
 })
```

Comment: Instead of sending a large message, consider instead sending a small message with a reference to the rest of the data that lives in the database.  The client can query the database directly to get the data.

Answer (score -2):

I think this is useful to you.

```
  public static final String SMS_BUNDLE = "pdus";

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();

        if (intentExtras != null) {
        Object[] sms = (Object[]) intentExtras.get(SMS_BUNDLE);
        String smsMessageStr = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; ++i) {
        String format = intentExtras.getString("format");
        SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i], format);

            String smsBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
            String address = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();

            smsMessageStr += "SMS From: " + address + "\n";
            smsMessageStr += smsBody + "\n";
        }

        MainActivity inst = MainActivity.instance();
        inst.updateInbox(smsMessageStr);
    }
}
```